# why dot product of normalized vector is always data size -1

Tags: r, math, linear-algebra

I don't understand why dot product of normalized vector is always data size -1.

```
a <- scale(rnorm(100))
crossprod(a)
# equal = 100 - 1 = 99

b <- scale(runif(50))
crossprod(b)
# equal = 50 - 1 = 49

c <- scale(rchisq(30, 5))
crossprod(c)
# equal = 30 - 1 = 29
```

I want to know mathematical understanding.

Comment: Please read the documentation of `scale()`, section **Details**: for the scaled data the standard deviation is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in LaTex, but proof may help you to understand:

Your values are scaled, so: [x_i-mean(X)] / sd(X).

Crossprod does sum of squares of x_i = Sum_i  ( [x_i-mean(X)])^2

Variance (squared sd):  var(X) = sd^2(X) = 1/(n-1) * Sum_i  ( [x_i-mean(X)])^2

Crossprod = Sum_i ([x_i-mean(X)] / sd(X))^2) = 1/sd(X)^2 * Sum_i ( [x_i-mean(X)]^2) = 1/(1/(n-1)) = n-1

Comment: Oh. I got it. Thank you.